# Where are Kernel Headers for Fedora 21?

Tags: linux-kernel, headers, fedora-21

I'm trying to install VMware on Fedora 21. I've installed the kernel headers:

```
sudo yum install kernel-headers-`uname -r`
```

And I receive the following message:

```
Package kernel-headers-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64 already installed
```

However, there's nothing in `/usr/src/kernels`:

```
$ ls /usr/src
$ debug     kernels
$ ls /usr/src/kernels/
$
```

I guess something has changed, and I'm looking in the wrong place.

Where are the kernel headers located in Fedora 21?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To compile programs that build Linux kernel modules, such as VMware Tools, VMware Workstation, etc., you should install both the relevant `kernel-headers` and `kernel-devel` packages.

The `kernel-headers` package provides include files for compiling *userland* programs, especially the C library, while the `kernel-devel` package provides include files for compiling *kernel modules* (which VMware Tools is full of).

---

Also note carefully that VMware currently recommends that you *not* compile VMware Tools yourself on guest operating systems which provide `open-vm-tools`, but you should install `open-vm-tools` instead. For example:

```
yum install open-vm-tools
```

Comment: after running yum -y kernel-devel-\`uname -r\` kernel-headers-\`uname -r\` my installation hangs on the message `Starting vmware-tools (via systemctl)`

Answer (score 3):

The `yum` command is `rpm` based, and so to list the contents of a package use

```
rpm -ql package-name
```

So in your case

```
rpm -ql kernel-headers-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64
```

should reveal where your headers are.

Have you tried `/usr/include/linux`? When you find out could you post the actual location?

Hope this helps